# How to get bootstrap label to fill up remaining area of kendoToolbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have a kendoToolbar with 3 `button`s in it and a `label`, chances are in the end I'll end up adding another `button` or a dropdown menu in it for exporting the grid data, anyhow..

I was wondering how I can make the bootstrap `label` fill up the remaining area of the toolbar. Reason being is because when a user navigates to this grid I would like them to know where they are.

Right now it looks like this:

[image: Current]

And this is how I am wanting it to look like

[image: Expected]

Right now my code looks like this:

```
$("#customerToolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [
    {
        template: "&nbsp<button type='button' id='AddRecord' onClick='CustomerPopupEditor()' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Add</button> &nbsp"
    },
    {
        template: "<button type='button' id='edit' class='btn btn-warning myEdit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> &nbsp"
    },
    {
        template: "<button type='button' id='delete' class='btn btn-danger myDelete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete</button>"
    },
    {
        template: "<div class='label label-success'>Customers</div>"
    }
    ]
});
```

and here is [**dojo**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Cwm/azomO)

**EDIT**

It doesn't necessarily need to be a `label` either to fill up the remaining space of the toolbar, it can be anything that will give the similar effect to what I want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flexbox` you can achieve this.

Toggle full-page to see result.

**NOTE:** I used `body` in CSS to override the already used CSSs without using `!important`.

```css
/*CSS changes*/

body .k-toolbar {
  display: flex;
}
body .k-toolbar .k-button,
body .k-toolbar > * {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
body .k-toolbar-last-visible {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
body .label {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1.5em
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="customerToolbar">
</div>
<!-- Script -->
<script>
  $("#customerToolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [{
      template: "&nbsp<button type='button' id='AddRecord' onClick='CustomerPopupEditor()' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Add</button> &nbsp"
    }, {
      template: "<button type='button' id='edit' class='btn btn-warning myEdit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> &nbsp"
    }, {
      template: "<button type='button' id='delete' class='btn btn-danger myDelete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete</button>"
    }, {
      template: "<div class='label label-success'>Customers</div>"
    }]
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What about centering or styling the inner text?

Comment: I will be able to change the font size in the body .label?

Comment: yes of course, currently it is 75%, but you can of course, then you just need to adjust the `padding` because `align-items:center` is vertical aligning it :)

Comment: Perfect, it says I can award you the bounty in 23 hours, once the 23 hours are up then its all yours. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I hate to ask, but you can fix the layout of how it looks now? the buttons are spaced out more than what they should be

Comment: there is that `margin:0 1%` just adjust as it fits you better, being `top/bottom right/left`

Comment: just released the bounty to you